# How to use “IS NOT NULL” filter in frappe.get_list?

Tags: mysql, erpnext, frappe

Problem:
when i bench execute using frappe.get_list, nothing happen, i tried

- ("!=", “null”)
- ("!=", “None”)
- ("!=", “”)

i think the second parameter is wrong.

```
mortgage_details = frappe.get_list("Property Sales", fields=["*"],

                             filters={"mortgage_officer": ("!=", "null"), ## IS NOT NULL

                                      "mortgage_processing_end_date": ("!=", "null"),

                                      "docstatus": 1})
```

Comment: Try using `None` with no quotes. The quotes make it a string literal.

Comment: Do you have a link to the filter documentation? I can't find it at https://frappeframework.com/docs/v14/user/en/api/database

Comment: if using None with no quotes, nothing happen; if using none with no quotes (it shows none is not defined)

Comment: @Barmar, the link that you provided is the filter documentation but there is no filter for `IS NOT NULL`. 
the related link below is only show `IS NULL`
https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/is-null-filter-in-frappe-query/20886

Comment: @Barmar, i found the answer, i think is the permission issue, using `("!=", "")` in `frappe.get_all` will help, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how that could work. How does it tell whether you mean `!= ''` or `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I don't see any filter documentation at that link. There are some examples in the code snippets, but no detailed documentation of the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/pull/6824), you can make your `IS NULL` and `NOT NULL` filter like this:

```py
mortgage_details = frappe.get_list(
    "Property Sales", 
    fields=["*"],
    filters={
        "mortgage_officer": ["is", "set"], ## IS NOT NULL,
        # "mortgage_officer": ["is", "not set"], ## IS NULL, 
        "docstatus": 1
    })
```